# Flutter - Grabbing the Id's of individual Tabs

Tags: flutter, woocommerce-rest-api

Hello please am a new developer in flutter, developing a mobile app using the woocommerce api. I have passed the individual categories into tabs but I need to grab their individual id to pass to the api to call their products. What am getting is all the id's in the tabs.

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXyvf.gif)

This is the ui code

```
  CategoryDetails({Key key, this.categoryId, this.categoryName})
      : super(key: key);

  final String categoryName;
  final int categoryId;

  @override
  _CategoryDetailsState createState() => _CategoryDetailsState();
}

class _CategoryDetailsState extends State<CategoryDetails> {
  APIService apiService;

  @override
  void initState() {
    apiService = APIService();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _brandsList();
  }

  Widget _brandsList() {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: apiService.getbrands(this.widget.categoryId),
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<ProductCategory>> model) {
        if (model.hasData) {
          return _brandsTab(model.data);
        }
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _brandsTab(brands) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: brands.length,
      child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            elevation: 1,
            centerTitle: true,
            bottomOpacity: 1.0,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
            automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
            title: Text(
              //'Franko Trading',
              this.widget.categoryName,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                  onPressed: () {},
                  color: Colors.black),
              IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
                  onPressed: () {},
                  color: Colors.black),
            ],
            bottom: TabBar(
              labelPadding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
              indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
              isScrollable: true,
              labelColor: Colors.black87,
              indicator: UnderlineTabIndicator(),
              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 19,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black45,
              unselectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
              tabs: List<Widget>.generate(
                  brands.length, (index) => Text(brands[index].categoryName)),
            ),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
              children: List.generate(brands.length, (index) {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: brands.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Center(child: Text(brands[index].categoryId.toString()));
              },
            );
          })
              //Center(child: Text("Settings Tab")),
              )),
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: sir please can you tell me url for calling brand category?

Comment: am using woocommerce api for my backend. so depending on your application. To get categories from woocommerce api ulr  `apiurl/products/categories` and to get subcategories `apiurl/products/categories/parent=categoryID`

Answer (score 0):

tabs are stacked in the order you put them. so, the first tab is always having the index of 0. you can use that index to cross-reference a list of Category IDs.

```
List<String> catIDList = ['A','B','C'];
```

if you need the id of the tab 1,

```
String id = catIDList[index];
```

Comment: This is the return  ```return Center(child: Text(brands[index].categoryId.toString()));``` but it grabbing all the ids of all the tabs